# Was an index theorem for manifold with local boundary condition proven?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-operators, index-theory

I would like to ask a question on the bibliography of the index theorems on manifold with boundary.

Before my bibliographical research my understanding of the field was that for manifold with boundary, the only way to obtain a generalisation of the Atiyah-Singer theorem was to impose very strange global boundary conditions to dirac operator leading to the Atiah-Singer-Patodi theorem.

However I recently read the english wikipedia page on the index theorem and it says that the case where we impose local boundary conditions (more natural in physics) "was worked out by Atiyah and Bott". After some research it seems to me that this make reference to the papers [1] and [2] (that I manage to found in the book "michael atiyah, collected works Vol 3") which effectively seems to claim such result.

However I wonder if I can trust these papers for several reasons. First they seems to be papers which were associated to seminars and I don't know if they are formally peer-reviewed. In particular they seems to be written shortly after the paper [3] which is considered by wikipedia to be an annoncement and not a published proof. The series of published papers [4] start to be published later in 1968 (so after [1] and [2]) and if the introduction of [4] planned to published a proof of the local boundary case in futur paper, the other papers of the series do not contained in fact such a result.

After that the claim of an index theorem on manifold with local boundary conditions seems to disapear in the literrature. For example if the paper [2] is mentioned in the Atiyah/Patodi/Singer paper [5], it is only for the obstruction to have boundary condition for the signature operator (the theorem by itself, is not claimed even if it is in direct relation with the subject of [5]).

Because of all of that, I have mixed feelings on the fact that the result of [2] and [3] is proved but I do not came across any paper that confirmed that suspicions and my knowledge of the subject is too small to be sure by myself. Can anyone help me to understand if there is today an index theorem for manifold with open boundary condition or if it remains an unsolved problem ?

[1] M. Atiyah and R. Bott, The index problem for manifold with boundary. Differential analysis (paper presented at the Bombay Colloquium 1964), Oxford University Press, 175-86

[2] M. Atiyah, The index theorem for manifold with boundary, Appendix I in seminar on the Atiyah-Singer index theorem, Annals of Math.,Study57, Princeton Univ.Press (1965),337-51

[3] Atiyah, Michael F.; Singer, Isadore M. (1963), "The Index of Elliptic Operators on Compact Manifolds", Bull. Amer. Math. Soc., 69 (3): 422–433, doi:10.1090/S0002-9904-1963-10957-X

[4] Atiyah, Michael F.; Singer, Isadore M. (1968a), "The Index of Elliptic Operators I", Annals of Mathematics, 87 (3): 484–530, doi:10.2307/1970715, JSTOR 1970715
which is part of a series of 4 papers with same name (up to numerotation II/III/IV)

[5] Atiyah, M. F., Patodi, V. K., & Singer, I. M. (1975, January). Spectral asymmetry and Riemannian geometry. I. In Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society (Vol. 77, No. 1, pp. 43-69). Cambridge University Press.

Comment: You can trust Atiyah and Bott's paper.   You may not like the general result https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5649

Comment: The above  includes local boundary conditions.  In physics most operators are self-adjoint  and, if they are also Fredholm, they have index zero.  If you could, like physicists,   give a concrete  example of boundary condition that interests you, perhaps you could receive  a more precise answer.